# Hibernate dynamic load strategy for second level entities

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

```
 class SomeClass {
  List strings;
  OtherClass otherClass;
 }



class OtherClass {
  List listOfOtherClass
 }
```

So I have SomeClass and I can load it's strings dynamicly via criteria's `setFetchMode("strings", someFetchStrategy)`.
But I want to load `listOfOtherClass` too. I tried doing `setFetchMode("listOfOtherClass", JOIN)`, `setFetchMode("otherClass", JOIN)` but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. You need to do `setFetchMode("otherClass.listOfOtherClass", JOIN)`